# Show values in PowerPivot only for total/subtotal

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I have a value column coming from simple count() in PowerPivot Data model.

Is there any way to show count value only in subtotal/grand total rows, without displaying value `1` in each individual row?

I would like to see all rows like on the screenshots, with all AttendProjectMembers name visible, but value for "count members" column should be only in subtotal/grand total rows (red box), all other rows in this column should be empty.

Each AttendProjectMember can be assigned to the team only once, so count value makes no sense for row with name, I want to see only count of members in each team - but still I want to see names.

[image: Pivot table]

Edit.

I found the solution. One has to use HASONEFILTER() function:

> Count Members:=if(HASONEFILTER(AttendeesHPT[AttendProjectMembers]),"",COUNT(AttendeesHPT[AttendProjectMembers]))

[image: Table with HASONEFILTER effect applied]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Agreed, I'm not really sure what you are looking for. One thing you can do with a pivot table is select the cell to the right of the headers and insert a auto-filter.  You could then hide the 1s.

Comment: You can expand/collapse details by clicking on those `-` or `+` signs next to items in your pivot table. Or get rid of your A`AttendProjectMembers` column from your pivot table...

Comment: I've expanded the question, hope it will makes it more clear.